# Buscar en DataGridView

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

tengo un DataGridView cargado con nombres y lo que quiero hacer es buscar el primer nombre que concuerde con lo que el usuario escribe pero, la escritura tiene que ser mismo sobre el DataGridView es decir no puedo poner un TextBox, por el momento tengo hecho que en el evento keypress del formulario busque el primer elemento que comience con el caracter de la tecla apretada y lo seleccione, pero debe de funcionar si se escribe mas de una letra trambien, Esta es una funcionalidad que ya existe en listview y me gustaria implementarla en el DataGridView

```
private void dgvMensageria_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMensageria.Rows) {
            row.Selected = false;
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMensageria.Rows) {
            row.Selected = row.Cells[ColUsuarioDgv.Index].Value.ToString().ToUpper()[0] == e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper()[0];
            if (row.Selected) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y si el datagridview tiene varias columnas por cual vas a realizar la busqueda? Tu pregunta esta un poco extranna

Comment: la busqueda siempre va a ser en base a una columna concreta. En este caso ColUsuarioDgv